# how to integrate yolov8 realtime detection in angular

Tags: angular, opencv, yolov8

I'm working on integrating real-time object detection using YOLOv8 into an Angular project and encountering difficulties. My main goal is to use YOLOv8 to process a video stream (either from a webcam or uploaded video) and display the detected objects within my Angular application.